# Virtualenv & Conda Env conflict

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I've recently installed virtualenv under pip and created one virtual environment. Previously, I've created couple virtual environments under anaconda. So when I tried to activate the anaconda virtual environment, it somehow shows up as the environment I created with virtualenv.

I've tried to:
- remove the virtualenv fold
- uninstall virtualenv entirely in both pip & anaconda

still not working :(

Here's an example:

```
Ks-MacBook-Air:~ KerryChowChow$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
dsi                      //anaconda/envs/dsi
sklearn                  //anaconda/envs/sklearn
tensorflow               //anaconda/envs/tensorflow
workplace                //anaconda/envs/workplace
root                  *  //anaconda
```

but when I typed:

```
Ks-MacBook-Air:~ KerryChowChow$ source activate dsi
```

it gave me this:

```
(under30) Ks-MacBook-Air:~ KerryChowChow$
```

in Terminal.